# WPF Slider Tooltip shows up with incorrect placement

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, slider, tooltip

I have a Tooltip that I would like to display above a Slider, but it's showing up below. Here is the code:

```
   <Slider Grid.Column="0"
           x:Name="Slider"
           Style="{DynamicResource VideoSlider}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Minimum="0" 
           Maximum="1" 
           Value="{Binding CurrentPosition}"
           PreviewMouseUp="Slider_PreviewMouseUp"
           TickFrequency="0.02"
           IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
           IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" 
           SmallChange="0.03"
           LargeChange="1"
           TickPlacement="TopLeft"
           AutoToolTipPlacement="TopLeft"
           Foreground="Black"
           MouseMove="Slider_MouseMove">
              <Slider.ToolTip>
                  <ToolTip x:Name="SliderTooltip">
                      <StackPanel>
                          <TextBlock x:Name="Playtime"
                                     Text="Test"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                  </ToolTip>
              </Slider.ToolTip>
           </Slider>
```

As you can see I have the "AutoToolTipPlacement" set to TopLeft, so why does the tooltip show up below the Slider?